# JSON Valid Chars

Tags: json

Is the presence of a \' within double quotes "invalid" in the context of a JSON response?
Is there a definitive JSON spec that could give me an answer?

Comment: You can verify any JSON text in http://www.jsonlint.com/. The only restriction is the site support no primitive types like "test" or 123. To verity such primitive types just place there in [] (like ["test"] or [123]). Moreover if you do no manual JSON serialization and use `JSON.stringify` instead (from http://www.json.org/js.html) or other standrd JSON serializer (DataContractJsonSerializer or JavaScriptSerializer in .NET), you will no time think about which charachters should be escaped in JSON and which not.

Answer (score 12):

Check out http://www.json.org/ and scroll down to the "String" diagram.

You can see there how the \ is a "control" character. If you want a literal backslash within your JSON, you'll need to escape it: `"\\"` is a valid JSON string, for example.