# Merge multiple lines based on pattern with sed

Tags: json, bash, git, awk, sed

This is an output example of git's log in JSON format.
The issue is that, from time to time, the `body` key has got break lines in it, which makes the parsing of this JSON file impossible, unless it gets corrected.

```
# start of cross-section
[{
  "commit-hash": "11d07df4ce627d98bd30eb1e37c27ac9515c75ff",
  "abbreviated-commit-hash": "11d07df",
  "author-name": "Robert Lucian CHIRIAC",
  "author-email": "robert.lucian.chiriac@gmail.com",
  "author-date": "Sat, 27 Jan 2018 22:33:37 +0200",
  "subject": "@fix(automation): patch versions aren't released",
  "sanitized-subject-line": "fix-automation-patch-versions-aren-t-released",
  "body": "Nothing else to add.

Fixes #24.",
 "commit-notes": ""
},
# end of cross-section
```

I've been going through `sed`'s manual page and the explanation is quite hard to be digested. Does anyone have some suggestions on how I can put the value of `body` into one line and hence get rid of all those break lines? The idea is to make the file valid in order to be able to parse it.

At the end, it should look like this:

```
...
"body": "Nothing else to add. Fixes #24."
...
```

Comment: Did you tried `jq` utility?

Comment: Just tried it with the simplest filter and I got a `parse error: Invalid string: control characters from U+0000 through U+001F must be escaped at line 42 ..`. That line coincides with what I've shown in the above example. Any thoughts?

Comment: It seems that what you have *isn't* JSON: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3234150/json-valid-chars (control characters, including newlines, are explicitly forbidden). The best fix would be to whatever generated this in the first place, to make it generate valid JSON; anything else is just papering over defects and in my experience, you'll eventually encounter an unfixable defect. (Still, your question is an accurate summary of the state of affairs, I think.)

Comment: The body was generated with `%b` placeholder found here https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log. And I've got to agree with you - what's broken from the ground up is going to bite you at some point. I've looked for a solution to get `git log` to remove all break lines, but I've reached a dead-end on that one. Any idea?

Comment: @torek I think I can generate this JSON file with an empty value associated to `body` key and then iteratively, I could add the corespondent values with a curated `git log -n[X] --pretty=format:%b` (where `X` is the index of the commit).

Comment: Best to avoid extracting anything (%s or %b, or even author and committer names) directly if it's not going to be passed through a sanitizer first. If you have a local clone of the repo you can use a real JSON encoder, even if you have to write one, so that the only thing you need initially is the hash ID (from which all else can be extracted safely later).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This, using GNU awk for multi-char RS and patsplit(), will work whether there's escaped quotes in the input or not:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { RS="^$"; ORS="" }
{
    gsub(/@/,"@A")
    gsub(/\\"/,"@B")
    nf = patsplit($0,flds,/"[^"]*"/,seps)
    $0 = ""
    for (i=0; i<=nf; i++) {
        $0 = $0 gensub(/\s*\n\s*/," ","g",flds[i]) seps[i]
    }
    gsub(/@B/,"\\\"")
    gsub(/@A/,"@")
    print
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
# start of cross-section
[{
  "commit-hash": "11d07df4ce627d98bd30eb1e37c27ac9515c75ff",
  "abbreviated-commit-hash": "11d07df",
  "author-name": "Robert Lucian CHIRIAC",
  "author-email": "robert.lucian.chiriac@gmail.com",
  "author-date": "Sat, 27 Jan 2018 22:33:37 +0200",
  "subject": "@fix(automation): patch versions aren't released",
  "sanitized-subject-line": "fix-automation-patch-versions-aren-t-released",
  "body": "Nothing else to add. Fixes #24.",
 "commit-notes": ""
},
# end of cross-section
```

It replaces every escaped quote with a string that cannot exist in the input (which the first gsub() ensures) then operates on the "..." strings then puts the escaped quotes back.

Comment: I know some time has passed since I created this question and now I had to go back to the project that needed this implementation. I have got to say this solution is more reliable than the other one - this does handle escaped quotes. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You could try this but escaped double quotes in the string values will probably break it:

- Using double quote as the field separator, we count how many fields are in each line.
- We expect there to be 5 fields.
- If there are 4, then we have an "open" string.
- If we're in an open string, when we see 2 fields, that line contains the closing double quote

```
awk -F'"' '
    NF == 4              {in_string = 1} 
    in_string && NF == 2 {in_string = 0} 
    {printf "%s%s", $0, in_string ? " " : ORS}
' file.json
```

---

To handle the inner quotes problem, let's try replacing all escaped quotes with other text, handle the newlines, then restore the escaped quotes:

```
awk -F'"' -v escaped_quote_marker='!@_Q_@!' '
    {gsub(/\\\"/, escaped_quote_marker)}
    NF == 4              {in_string = 1}
    in_string && NF == 2 {in_string = 0}
    {
        gsub(escaped_quote_marker, "\\\"")
        printf "%s%s", $0, in_string ? " " : ORS
    }
' <<END
[{
    "foo":"bar",
    "baz":"a string with \"escaped
quotes\" and \"newlines\"
."
}]
END
```

```
[{
    "foo":"bar",
    "baz":"a string with \"escaped quotes\" and \"newlines\" ."
}]
```

I assume git log is at least kind enough to escape quotes for you.

Comment: Yeah, escaped double quotes break it. Do you see any solution on ignoring escaped quotes? Also, what @torek said in one of the comments to my question got me thinking - we're only hiding the real issue and that's linked to how this invalid JSON gets generated with `git log`. No matter what policy, someone will include quotes in his commit sometime by mistake and that's going to mess everything up.

Comment: Don't pick some random string that you **hope** won't exist in the input, create a string that know definitely can't exist in the input, see the gsub()s I used at https://stackoverflow.com/a/48532542/1745001for how I ensured that `@B` isn't in the input.

Answer (score 1):

`sed` doesn't handle multi-line input *easily*. You may use `perl` in `slurp` mode:

```
perl -0777 -pe 's~("body":\h*"|\G(?<!^))([^\n"]*)\n+~$1$2 ~' file

# start of cross-section
[{
  "commit-hash": "11d07df4ce627d98bd30eb1e37c27ac9515c75ff",
  "abbreviated-commit-hash": "11d07df",
  "author-name": "Robert Lucian CHIRIAC",
  "author-email": "robert.lucian.chiriac@gmail.com",
  "author-date": "Sat, 27 Jan 2018 22:33:37 +0200",
  "subject": "@fix(automation): patch versions aren't released",
  "sanitized-subject-line": "fix-automation-patch-versions-aren-t-released",
  "body": "Nothing else to add. Fixes #24.",
 "commit-notes": ""
},
# end of cross-section
```

- `\G` asserts position at the end of the previous match or the start of the string for the first match.
- `(?<!^)` is a negative lookahead to ensure we don't match start position.
- `("body":\h*"|\G(?<!^))` expression matches `"body":` or end of previous match

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/PPIwos/1)

Comment: Starting to understand it - still need to. And that RegEx demo is fantastic. Until then, I'm wondering why does it only work on apparently a couple of cases. After applying this command, some of these instances get "cured", whilst others are still not fixed. There's no reason in showing an example, as it looks exactly the same way as the one I put.

Comment: Some cases where it may not work is if there is a space between `"body"` and next colon or if there is another line break character instead of `\n`